# Import words from text file in json

Tags: python, json, chatbot

I want to import words from text file to json. So instead of
`"patterns": ["hi", "hello", "hey"]`
i want it to take words from a txt. file and use them in the place of `["hi", "hello", "hey"]`
For example
"patterns": [words.txt]
and when someone types a word its searched through the file instead of directly from the code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot import files into JSON, but what you *can* do is read from a text file in your Python and inject those values into the created object from parsing the JSON.